# Isomorphism between quotient of polynomial ring and polynomial ring $\Bbb Z[x]/\Bbb Z \cong \Bbb Z[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, group-isomorphism

The question is as follows:

Consider the group $(\Bbb{Z}[x], +)$. Is the group $\Bbb Z[x]/\Bbb Z$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z[x]$, where $\Bbb Z[x]$ is a polynomial ring?

I am not able to develop any particular isomorphism for this.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It would help to consider the abelian groups mentioned as $\mathbb{Z}$ modules instead. The result then follows from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423668/411639).

Comment: Please do not deface questions that already have answers (upvoted and accepted, even!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the principal ideal $(x) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ as an abelian group. Then, the homomorphism $\phi: (x) \to \mathbb{Z}[x]/\mathbb{Z}$ given by $\phi(f) = [f]$ is an isomorphism. If $\phi(f) = 0$, then given some expansion $f = \sum_{k = 0}^n c_k x^k $ we have that all $c_k$ are zero except $c_0$. Hence, $f \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $\mathbb{Z} \cap (x) =\{0\}$, it follows that $f = 0$. Thus $\phi$ is injective.

Conversely, if some $[g] \in \mathbb{Z}[x]/\mathbb{Z}$ we can expand $g = \sum_{k = 0}^n b_kx^k$. Then, let $h = \sum_{k = 1}^n b_kx^k \in (x)$. It follows from their definitions that $g - h = b_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence $\phi(h) = [g]$ proving that $\phi$ is bijective.

Comment: Finally, $(x)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as an abelian group, via $f \mapsto xf : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to (x)$. To package all of this together: $f \mapsto [xf] : \mathbb{Z}[x] \mapsto \mathbb{Z}[x]/\mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism of abelian groups.

Comment: Thanx @daniel-apsley for the detailed answer, I wanted to ask one thing that is it possible to define any other isomorphism than using the principal ideal?

Comment: @player9 Yes, as the other commenter added, the map $f \mapsto [xf]: \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]/\mathbb{Z}$  is an isomorphism by the same argument.

Comment: That does not count as a different map! The goal was to show that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\mathbb{Z}$, so it was not sufficient to show that $(x) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/\mathbb{Z}$ without further composing with an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to (x)$. In other words, $f \mapsto [xf]$ is the isomorphism you gave (just not entirely explicitly).

For a different isomorphism, we just precompose with a nontrivial automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. For example, $f \mapsto [-xf] : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]/\mathbb{Z}$ is a different isomorphism.

Comment: Conversely, if $a, b : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]/\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphisms, then $b^{-1} \circ a : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is an automorphism and the isomorphism $b \circ (b^{-1} \circ a) : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]/\mathbb{Z}$ is just $a$. We conclude that the set of isomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]/\mathbb{Z}$ is precisely $$\{f \mapsto [x \alpha(f)] : \alpha \in \operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}[x])\}.$$

Comment: Finally, since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is free on $\aleph_0$ generators, there are $2^{\aleph_0} = \lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert$ abelian group automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Thus, there are the same number of isomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]/\mathbb{Z}$.